# Unable to mount DVD external hard drive

Tags: usb, mount, dvd, media

My external DVD hard drive stopped being recognized by my laptop. Originally, it was automatically recognized by just plugging in the USB cable. Here is what the terminal tells me:

```
me@me-thinkpadx1:~$ wodim --devices 
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sg0'  rwrw-- : 'ASUS' 'SDRW-08D2S-U'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then:

```
me@me-thinkpadx1:~$ sudo mount /dev/sr0 /media/asus_dvd/
mount: /media/asus_dvd: no medium found on /dev/sr0.
```

Then again :

```
root@me-thinkpadx1:/home/me# dmesg | tail
[ 1648.756668] usb 1-3: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 1648.756672] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: USB2.0 External
[ 1648.756674] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 97 436033521790
[ 1648.760976] usb-storage 1-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1648.761333] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-3:1.0
[ 1649.773381] scsi 0:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ASUS     SDRW-08D2S-U     BA01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[ 1649.775314] sr 0:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[ 1649.788617] sr 0:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[ 1649.806052] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 1649.806507] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
```

I feel like the message "Power-on or device reset occurred" is crucial here, but I do not know how to restore the device properly and get it to work again.

Remarkably, the drive responds to the command :

```
eject /dev/sr0
```

Also (not sure it is relevant) I had a look at the /etc/fstab file and looks like this (I removed commented lines)

```
UUID=fccb78f2-f2ca-47e9-82df-d0d9c4582725 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Thanks!

Comment: The fstab file looks clean (only root partition and swapfile). It's definitely not related to the issue. Can you post the output of `lsusb` to check if the problem is on the USB cable or bus? The error message `no medium found on /dev/sr0` seems to indicate that the drive is unable to read the DVD disc, though.

Comment: Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS7500 Touch Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f2:b5c1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Integrated Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp.

Comment: Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1c6b:a223 Philips & Lite-ON Digital Solutions Corporation Mass Storage Device
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 1199:9079 Sierra Wireless, Inc. Sierra Wireless EM7455 Qualcomm Snapdragon X7 LTE-A
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 056a:5087 Wacom Co., Ltd Pen and multitouch sensor
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Hmm, it's not the USB cable or bus, since the drive is detected here: `Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1c6b:a223 Philips & Lite-ON Digital Solutions Corporation Mass Storage Device `

Comment: Try ejecting a disc from the drive from the command line with `sudo eject /dev/sg0` to see if the drive responds?

Comment: Sorry, I did not write that I have indeed already tried `eject /dev/sr0` and it works.  The command `eject /dev/sg0` leads to `eject: unable to eject, last error: Invalid argument'

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, it should be `/dev/sr0`. I'm starting to think that it's the DVD disc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the GNOME Disks utility to check whether the drive is detected or not, and if it is detected there, whether the DVD disc contains any readable partitions.

Comment: I have checked. The drive is indeed detected, but the message "No Media" appears in the "Volumes" section. I would add a screenshot, but, apparently, this is not possible in the comments :)

Comment: Interesting. Try swapping the DVD disc and see whether that particular disc is faulty (maybe it wasn't finalized properly after the last burn)?

Comment: Also tried. Changing DVD disc does not lead to recognition as well

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if it has anything to do with DVD decryption. Try this link: https://www.linuxliteos.com/forums/installing-software/dvd-drive-not-recognised/msg50721/?PHPSESSID=83gl3mhifoq9uertg334rihj5q#msg50721

Comment: `sudo apt install libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly libdvd-pkg`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libdvdread4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libdvdread4' has no installation candidate

Comment: Otherwise, after reboot, no change

Comment: Ah, that one's specific to Ubuntu Bionic (18.04). If you're on Focal (20.04) the corresponding package is `libdvdread7`

Comment: Indeed I am on Focal, and I had `libdvdread7` already installed